# Colocar dois atributos numa célula

Tags: java

Têm alguma estrutura, `List`, `LinkedList`, etc., que me permita colocar dois atributos na célula? Por exemplo, um inteiro e uma *string* em cada célula.

Comment: Poderia explicar qual seria a utilização? Achei um pouco vaga sua pergunta, não tenho certeza de qual é a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Você teria que fazer algo assim:

```
class MinhaEstutura {
    public int MeuInteiro;
    public String MinhaString;
}
```

A estrutura, no caso, ficaria assim:

```
ArrayList<MinhaEstrutura> lista = new ArrayList<MinhaEstrutura>();
```

Comment: Só um detalhe, mas, para seguir o padrão do Java, sugiro começar o nome de variáveis com minúscula: `meuInteiro`, `minhaString`.

Answer (score 0):

**Exemplo**

```
//Criação e Adição
Map<Integer, String> dic = new HashMap<>();
dic.put(1, "Nome 1");
dic.put(2, "Nome 2");
dic.put(3, "Nome 3");
dic.put(4, "Nome 4");

//Leitura de cada item adicionado
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> itr =  dic.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    Entry<Integer,String> item = itr.next();
    System.out.println(item.getKey().toString() + " " + item.getValue());
}
```